# Set input field attribute in Thymeleaf from database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table in the database with fields like below which holds my form input's attributes:

```
@Column(name = "propertyname")
private String propertyname;
@Column(name = "propertyvalue")
private String propertyvalue;
@Column(name = "propertytype")
private String propertytype;
@Column(name = "propertyrequired")
private String propertyrequired;
@Column(name = "propertysize")
private String propertysize;
@Column(name = "propertymin")
private String propertymin;
```

Now I am getting these as bean fields in Thymeleaf template. But keep getting template parsing error (on the same line as below). I am trying to achieve below:

```
<input th:field="${modelAttribute.beanPropertyList[__${rowStat.index}__].propertyname}" th:errorclass="is-invalid" th:required="${modelAttribute.beanPropertyList[__${rowStat.index}__].propertyrequired}" th:min="${modelAttribute.beanPropertyList[__${rowStat.index}__].propertymin}" th:max="${modelAttribute.beanPropertyList[__${rowStat.index}__].propertymax}"/>
```

What am I doing wrong? or what is the correct approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

`th:field` doesn't work like that. It requires a `th:object="${foo}` as a form backing bean. Then `th:field="*{bar}"` will set the input's `name="bar"` and try to reflect on the model object called `foo` and get its field call `bar` to use the input's `value`

Try `th:name` and `th:value` separately. That also seems more plausible given your model.

Comment: okay. for simplicity, how can I use propertyrequired for the same form object?

Comment: You want `th:reqired="${bool}"` for some boolean expression.

Comment: `th:reqired="${bool}"` is not an option as I will get the data as I mentioned in my original question. As I do not have control on the DB and table(s) in my project.